# How to get OpenCL functioning for GPU rendering, AMD GPU?

Tags: gpu, opencl, compatibility

I'm running blender 2.79b and Blender won't recognize my card.

AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series, GCN 1st gen architecture
OpenCL™ Version: 24.20.11021.1000
Vulkan™ Driver Version: 2.0.33

Am I missing something to set it up in an official release?

I tried looking through GraphicAll.org for alternatives and found [This Version of Blender](http://graphicall.org/1200%22This%20Version%22)

While it did recognize my card the colors of light was incorrect and differed from the cpu rendering of the scene.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Blender manual on [OpenCL support](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl):

> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. (We only support graphics cards with GCN architecture 2.0 and above).

2.79 release log says:

> Due to various issues with drivers for AMD GCN 1.0 architecture, those cards are no longer supported for Cycles rendering "

The support was dropped so you need Blender 2.78c version or a newer card.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the info.
Looks like its time to go back .01 till I can upgrade this old machine.